# Append not saving for external file in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that when I run a new dict entry that it actually saves. Before last exception, when you "print(dictio.fullDict3[firstLetter])", it shows the new appended dict entry, but doesn't actually save in the external file called dictio.

The following is the main:

```
import fileinput
import dictio
from dictio import fullDict3

while True:
    try:
        srcTxt = input("Input word you want to look up: ")
        firstLetter = srcTxt[0]
        print(dictio.fullDict3[firstLetter][srcTxt])
    except: 
        try:
                queryInput = input('What does '+srcTxt+' mean?: ')       
                with open("C:\\Users...\\dictio.py", "a"):                 
                    dictio.fullDict3[firstLetter].update({srcTxt:queryInput})
                    print(dictio.fullDict3[firstLetter])                              
        except:
                    print("error has occured.")
```

The following is the external file called dictio.py that holds the dictionary:

```
fullDict3 = {
    '0':{
        '0data':'0datttaaa',
        '0mada':'0mmmaadaa'
    },
    'a':{
        'arbre':'tree',
        'arc-en-ciel':'rainbow'
    },
    'b':{
        'bierre':'beer',
        'belle':'beautiful'       
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you believe you are writing to a file?

Comment: I thought the "a" for append and the update would update that file's dict called fullDict3. I guess I was under the impression this did it because when I print the dict back after the operation, it's appended at the end of that dict.

Comment: Changing the value of a variable doesn't perform any file IO.  You are effectively discard the result of your `open` statement (python will open and possibly create the named file, but you never assign the return value from `open` to a variable and you never attempt to write to it using i/o statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the contents of a module by operating on the module's contents via import. There is no reason to import `fullDict3`. Instead, store your starting structure in `fullDict3.json`. Convert that file to a Python object via `json.load` -- that returns a dict you can change. When you have the updated dict ready to write to disk, save it via `json.dump`.

Comment: I thought there would be an easier moduled mean to just export without using json. I'll have to read up on json then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Haven't had much time to code, but finally fixed my issue after some reading and trial an error, for anyone that comes across this for answers, however, there could easily be a cleaner and more efficient way to get it done:

```
while True:
    try:
        srcTxt = input("Input word you want to look up: ")
        firstLetter = srcTxt[0]
        if srcTxt == "ESC":
            break
        print(dictio.fullDict3[firstLetter][srcTxt])
    except: 
        try:
            queryInput = input('What does '+srcTxt+' mean?: ')
            with open('C:\\Users...\\dictio.py', 'r') as f:
                fullDict3[firstLetter].update({srcTxt:queryInput})
                newDict = "fullDict3 = "+json.dumps(fullDict3)
            with open('C:\\Users...\\dictio.py', 'w') as f:
                f.write(newDict)
                f.close()
        except:
            print("error has occured.")
```